# Disable submit-button unless file_field_tag is not null in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, button

I have a form and in that form there is a submit_tag and a file field tag. As long as the user doesn't select a file the submit-button has to be disabled. When the file_field_tag is filled the button must then be enabled. What is the best way to do this?

This is my code:

```
<% form_tag({:action => 'match'}, {:multipart => true, :id => 'file_form_id'}) do %>


       <%= file_field_tag 'file', :size => 500%></p>

       <%= submit_tag 'Submit' -%>


<% end -%>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

I would use jQuery (or plain js) to bind a "change" event handler to the file_field_tag. 
Use the jQuery .val() function on the file_field_tag to check if a file is present. Code example below:

```html
  <%= form_tag(import_substitutions_path, :method => :post, multipart: true) do %>
    <%= file_field_tag 'file-field' %>
    <%= submit_tag "Import CSV", disabled: true, id: 'csv-import-submit' %>
  <% end %>

<script>
  var csvField = $('#file-field');
  var submitButton = $('#csv-import-submit');
  $(csvField).change(function() {
    var fileValue = $(csvField).val();
    if ( fileValue.empty() )  {
      $(submitButton).attr("disabled", true);
    } else {
      $(submitButton).attr("disabled", false);
    }
  })
</script>
```

I might also suggest an alternative solution of simply adding the `required: true` option on the file_field_tag:

`<%= file_field_tag 'file-field', required: true %>`

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to do that client-side with javascript.  Set the button disabled initially, then have a client-side method that's run when the input field changes.  The method would check if there's a value and enable the button.  I'd use unobtrusive js via jQuery.

Comment: And how would this look like? I now have :
  <%= submit_tag 'Submit', :disabled => true -%>, but how to enable it back? I can't find real examples on the internet...

Comment: Go to jquery.com.  You need to learn client-side JavaScript to make this work.  jQuery's the easiest way to do that.  You're not going to make it happen in your Ruby code.

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't answer your question but here's how I solved the same problem. I'm checking for the presence of the file in the controller method which uses it:

```
def import
  if params[:file].nil?
    redirect_to some_model_url, alert: "CSV document not present."
  else
    ModelName.import(params[:file])
    redirect_to some_model_url, notice: "Model Name collection imported."
  end
end
```